# How to get the feature ID of the first feature using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, feature-id

I'm trying to automate a workflow by making a PyQGIS script, but I haven't used Python before, so it's all a rollercoaster making it work. I noticed after some vector processing on a shapefile layer that my feature IDs changed from `0, 1, 2, 3,...` to `1, 2, 3, 4,...` in the resulting temporary layer. The question is why? And how can I find out which applies for a certain layer in PyQGIS?

I read somewhere that shapefiles don't have persistent IDs, so I thought it might have something to do with that (SHP vs temp layer). Is that it, or is there something more to it? I want my script to accept both types of input, and automatically figure out the FID of the first feature. How do I do that?

Let's say I have the following input layer

```
source = self.parameterAsSource(
   parameters,
   self.INPUT,
   context
```

Now what? How do I retrieve the first feature ID without knowing what it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most basic, but maybe not most elegant solution is to just break the feature iteration after the first feature using `break` command:

```
source = self.parameterAsSource(parameters, self.INPUT, context)

first_fid = None
for feat in source.getFeatures():
    first_fid = feat.id()
    break
```

`layer.getFeatures()` will always iterate in order of the feature ids if you do not add an order by statement.

Comment: Or just `first_id = next(source.getFeatures()).id()`.

Comment: @Mayo worth posting it as the more elegant answer ;)

Comment: Thank you! It works, and with @Mayo's suggestion even more elegantly so! My first thought was also to use .getFeatures(), but I didn't know how to index that. I couldn't find it in the [PyQGIS documentation](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.20/index.html). Where should I look for documentation on these commands?

Comment: Thank you @Joel and MrXsquared!! Joel are you talking about where to find info about commands like `next()`?

Comment: The `getFeature()` returns a feature iterator, ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-are-iterator-iterable-and-iteration) what's a python iterator) so you can use the [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) function to get each item at a time.

Comment: @Mayo: Yes, that's exactly it. As I said, I haven't used Python before, so when I'm faced with all commands I'm not always sure what belongs to QGIS and what belongs elsewhere, and where I should look in that case.